# Como apps fazem validação de login num servidor remoto?

Tags: mysql, servidor, app

Vamos supor que eu tenho um site com um banco de dados MySQL com os registros para login, então um app desktop ou mobile iria precisar de informações como host, root e senha para validar remotamente um formulário, mas isso não seria perigoso cada cópia do app ter essas informações, caso alguém decompile o app e veja os dados de conexão, ou existe outra maneira mais segura?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara da uma olhada nessa série de artigos desse link:
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/

Ta em ingles, mas ta bem explicadinho como funciona o processo de autenticação.
Por alto, cada cliente deve ter um token de acesso e vc vai acessar um link do seu banco de dados pra fazer esses logins no servidor. Então o login é feito em php dentro do ftp do site enquanto o seu app só faz acessar um link e mandar dados via esse link com um token de validação. Da uma conferida lá que é bem bacana.

Answer (score 0):

A comunicação se dá normalmente via webservice (API). Os dados de acesso ao banco de dados, MySQL por exemplo, ficam no servidor e não no cliente.

Não confunda dados de autenticação de um usuário do sistema com os dados de autenticação privados do servidor. A sua pergunta pergunta parece misturar ambos.